# Helmet at nodejs project. Content Security Policy directive

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I'm trying to add to the electronic signature project helmet. The widget is connected via iframe.

```
.use(helmet())
```

And after that there is a mistake of this kind
[image]

After that I tried to add directives to contentSecurityPolicy:

```
.use(helmet())
.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
       ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
       "script-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "http://localhost:80/"],
       "script-src-attr": ["'none'", "'unsafe-inline'", "http://localhost:80/"],
       "connect-src": ["'self'", "http://localhost:80/"],
       },
   })
)
```

But such a mistake arises, the solution of which I did not find, maybe there will be some advice
[image]

I use the script directly on the HTML page and read the information that helmet does not like it and I need to put the script into the module and connect it

```
<script type="module" src="..."></script>
```

I did it, but the error remains.
[image]

I tried many options, the question arose, how safe is it if you completely disable contentSecurityPolicy?

I will be grateful in helping this problem

**Update:**
I put the script into the module and the need for use of "script-src" and "script-src-attr" headers disappeared. Changed the resolution to "connect-src" to localhost:3030, and the first part of the script worked, but an error arose after trying to load the widget
[image]

After that, I added a resolution of the "frame-src" header

```
.use(
   helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
      directives: {
          ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "http://localhost:3030/"],
          "frame-src": ["'self'", "https://eu.msn.com.ua/"],
       },
   })
)
```

There are no more errors of the headlines, but the iframe widget *Does not open the site eu.msn.com.ua does not allow you to install the connection*. Without Helmet, the widget opens. What could be the reason in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The first CSP violation is for an inline script. You allow 'unsafe-inline' and the script is allowed to run.

The second CSP violation is for connect-src. You have allowed 'self' and http://localhost:80/, but the connect is attempting http://localhost:3030, which is blocked as you seem to be on the default port for 'self'.

In the third attempt you have two issues:

1. There is an inline event handler (onload, onerror, onclick etc). You *can* allow this in CSP level 3, but I would suggest to rewrite this with an event listener instead.
2. Connect is refused, but this time due to the CSP directive "default-src 'self'". Note that this policy is different from the policies used above where connect-src was defined.

Comment: Thank you, it became much more understandable in this matter, I did an update, could you tell me please?

Comment: Once you fix something more code is allowed to run and new CSP violations appear, but it seems like you got to the end of it. The error doesn't seem to be CSP specific and I don't know it or Helmet, so I'm not able to explain it.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help in clarifying CSP